PDF Text Extraction Using PDFBox
I'm extracting text from a PDF file using Apcahe PDFBox in an Spring Boot Application. The issue I'm facing is the last two words in some lines swap their position.
Here's what I tried:
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String[] lines = stripper.getText(document).split("\n");

Now, when I match the extracted text in the 'lines' and the actual sentence in PDF file there's a positional mismatch, e.g.:
key_1 : value_1 key_2 : value_2 key_3: value_3  // In PDF file
key_1 : value_1 key_2 : value_2 value_3 key_3 : // In extracted text

Why it is happening? Please suggest, how can I fix it?
Thanks

Try stripper.setSortByPosition(true) between lines 2 and 3.
